# Unknown device type using grub-probe

Tags: windows-10, grub, arch-linux

I first installed Windows 10 and then installed Arch Linux.
I want to use dual booting.

When I ran the `grub-probe` command twice, I got an warning and don't get the output on the second one.

```
# grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
966B-A03E

# grub-probe --target=hints_string /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
grub-probe: warning: unknown device type nvme0n1.
```

What is happening? And what should I do?

Comment: I have the same issue with my m.2 disk:

`08:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing os-prober and running it before generating grub config, like so (assuming Arch Linux):

```
sudo pacman -S os-prober
sudo os-prober
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

You should see "Windows Boot Manager" listed in the output. This resolved the issue for me on EFI/GPT Windows/Linux dual boot. Now from the GRUB menu, I successfully boot into Windows or Linux.

Credit: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1795551#p1795551